# Cannot login facebook after first login

Tags: android, facebook

I try create simple app login Facebook , when first login it done but when i logout and try login again it show error : Login error: Error occurred when logging. Please try again later

Here is code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private LoginButton loginButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    getFbKeyHash("org.code2care.fbloginwithandroidsdk");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            System.out.println("Facebook Login Successful!");
            System.out.println("Logged in user Details : ");
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
            System.out.println("User ID  : " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());
            System.out.println("Authentication Token : " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login cancelled by user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("Facebook Login failed!!");

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login unsuccessful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("Facebook Login failed!!");
        }
    });
}

public void getFbKeyHash(String packageName) {

    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                packageName,
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("YourKeyHash :", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            System.out.println("YourKeyHash: "+ Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent i) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, i);
}
```

in AndroidMainifest I added

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

In my setting I checked in Put My app in public? and Sign in once
What happened in here? please help me

Comment: insert callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create(); after setContentView.

Comment: No,it does not work

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781501/login-to-my-app-using-facebook-error-when-using-facebook-app/38781787#38781787

Comment: Ok..then try for update facebook application from your phone if you are using latest android-facebook sdk for android

Comment: Oh, I tried remove Facebook app in my device and login on my app it run very good when I login Facebook from dialog web.